# Using a function that builds a triangle. How to implement new line without ending triangle with a new line?

Tags: javascript, function, newline

Building a triangle using functions. One creates a set of stairs, the next creates the spaces used to build the triangle, and the last function puts them together to build the triangle. Can't figure out how to build it without returning a new line at the end.

tried setting the height in my triangle function to height - 1 then instead of returning stairLine (which includes new line) i would return stairLine += spaceLine(height - i , numberOfCharacters). This doesn't work since i and numberofCharacters are not defined outside of my for loop but am wondering if I can use something similar.

```js
// line function :
function line(size){
   let hashLine = '';
   for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       hashLine += "#";
  }
  return hashLine;
}
//console.log(line(5));

// stairs function :
function stairs(height){
  let stairLine = '';
  let newLine = "\n";
  for (let i = 0; i <= height; i++){
    stairLine += line(i) + newLine;
  } return stairLine
}
//console.log(stairs(5));

// spaceLine function :
function spaceLine(numSpaces, numChars){
  let myLine = '';
  let lineLength = numSpaces + numChars;
  for(i = 0; i < numSpaces  ; i++){
    myLine += " ";
  }
  myLine += line(numChars);
  for(i = 0; i < numSpaces  ; i++){
    myLine += " ";
  }
  return myLine;
}
//console.log(spaceLine(3,5));


// triangle function :
function triangle(height){
  let stairLine = '';
  let newLine = "\n";
  for (let i = 0; i < height; i++){
    let numberOfCharacters = 2*i+1;
    stairLine += spaceLine(height - i , numberOfCharacters) + newLine;
  }
    return stairLine;
}

console.log(triangle(5));
```

I expect the output to be

```
    #
   ###
  #####
 #######
#########
```

but i am getting

```
    #
   ###
  #####
 #######
#########
(new line here)
```

Comment: Consider rewriting your question so that it adheres more closely to the guidelines in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a check in your loop to omit the newline if it's the last iteration:

```
for (let i = 0; i < height; i++){
  let numberOfCharacters = 2*i+1;
  stairLine += spaceLine(height - i , numberOfCharacters);
  if (i !== height - 1) stairLine += newLine;
}
```